# Facing issues with layout

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, layout, view

This is my View File which I am trying to use with my common layout code file _layout.

```
@model AttendanceManagement.Models.AttendanceModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Dashboard";
}

<h2>Attendance</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserRole, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.UserRole, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserRole, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Email, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Email, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Password, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Password, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Password, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Mobile, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Mobile, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Mobile, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@*@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}*@
```

This is the common _layout file which is used to set common layout for all views in project.I have set Render Body() below but still facing issues.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <title>PAGE TITLE</title>
    <!-- Custom fonts for this template-->
    <link href="~/DashboardStyles/vendor/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito:200,200i,300,300i,400,400i,600,600i,700,700i,800,800i,900,900i" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Custom styles for this template-->
    <link href="~/DashboardStyles/css/sb-admin-2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body id="page-top">
    <!-- Page Wrapper -->
    <div id="wrapper">
        <!-- Sidebar -->
        <ul class="navbar-nav bg-gradient-primary sidebar sidebar-dark accordion" id="accordionSidebar">
            <!-- Sidebar - Brand -->
            <a class="sidebar-brand d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center" href="index.html">
                <div class="sidebar-brand-icon rotate-n-15">
                    <i class="fas fa-laugh-wink"></i>
                </div>
                <div class="sidebar-brand-text mx-3">SB Admin <sup>2</sup></div>
            </a>
            <!-- Divider -->
            <hr class="sidebar-divider my-0">
            <!-- Nav Item - Dashboard -->
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="index.html">
                    <i class="fas fa-fw fa-tachometer-alt"></i>
                    <span>Dashboard</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <!-- Divider -->
            <hr class="sidebar-divider">
            <!-- Heading -->
            <div class="sidebar-heading">
                Interface
            </div>
            <!-- Nav Item - Pages Collapse Menu -->
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link collapsed" href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
                    <i class="fas fa-fw fa-cog"></i>
                    <span>Components</span>
                </a>
                <div id="collapseTwo" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingTwo" data-parent="#accordionSidebar">
                    <div class="bg-white py-2 collapse-inner rounded">
                        <h6 class="collapse-header">Custom Components:</h6>
                        <a class="collapse-item" href="buttons.html">Buttons</a>
                        <a class="collapse-item" href="cards.html">Cards</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
            <!-- Nav Item - Utilities Collapse Menu -->
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link collapsed" href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseUtilities" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseUtilities">
                    <i class="fas fa-fw fa-wrench"></i>
                    <span>Utilities</span>
                </a>
                <div id="collapseUtilities" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingUtilities" data-parent="#accordionSidebar">
                    <div class="bg-white py-2 collapse-inner rounded">
                        <h6 class="collapse-header">Custom Utilities:</h6>
                        <a class="collapse-item" href="utilities-color.html">Colors</a>
                        <a class="collapse-item" href="utilities-border.html">Borders</a>
                        <a class="collapse-item" href="utilities-animation.html">Animations</a>
                        <a class="collapse-item" href="utilities-other.html">Other</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
            <!-- Divider -->
            <hr class="sidebar-divider">
            <!-- Heading -->
            <div class="sidebar-heading">
                Addons
            </div>
            <!-- Nav Item - Pages Collapse Menu -->
            <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsePages" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapsePages">
                    <i class="fas fa-fw fa-folder"></i>
                    <span>Pages</span>
                </a>
                <div id="collapsePages" class="collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingPages" data-parent="#accordionSidebar">
                    <div class="bg-white py-2 collapse-inner rounded">
                        <h6 class="collapse-header">Login Screens:</h6>
                        <a class="collapse-item" href="login.html">Login</a>
                        <a class="collapse-item" href="register.html">Register</a>
                        <a class="collapse-item" href="forgot-password.html">Forgot Password</a>
                        <div class="collapse-divider"></div>
                        <h6 class="collapse-header">Other Pages:</h6>
                        <a class="collapse-item active" href="404.html">404 Page</a>
                        <a class="collapse-item" href="blank.html">Blank Page</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
            <!-- Nav Item - Charts -->
            @*<li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="charts.html">
                    <i class="fas fa-fw fa-chart-area"></i>
                    <span>Charts</span>
                </a>
            </li>*@
            <!-- Nav Item - Tables -->
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="tables.html">
                    <i class="fas fa-fw fa-table"></i>
                    <span>Tables</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <!-- Divider -->
            <hr class="sidebar-divider d-none d-md-block">
            <!-- Sidebar Toggler (Sidebar) -->
            <div class="text-center d-none d-md-inline">
                <button class="rounded-circle border-0" id="sidebarToggle"></button>
            </div>
        </ul>
        <!-- End of Sidebar -->

        @RenderBody()

        <!-- Content Wrapper -->
        <div id="content-wrapper" class="d-flex flex-column">
            <!-- Main Content -->
            <div id="content">
                <!-- Topbar -->
                <nav class="navbar navbar-expand navbar-light bg-white topbar mb-4 static-top shadow">
                    <!-- Sidebar Toggle (Topbar) -->
                    <button id="sidebarToggleTop" class="btn btn-link d-md-none rounded-circle mr-3">
                        <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
                    </button>
                    <!-- Topbar Search -->
                    <form class="d-none d-sm-inline-block form-inline mr-auto ml-md-3 my-2 my-md-0 mw-100 navbar-search">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control bg-light border-0 small" placeholder="Search for..." aria-label="Search" aria-describedby="basic-addon2">
                            <div class="input-group-append">
                                <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button">
                                    <i class="fas fa-search fa-sm"></i>
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                    <!-- Topbar Navbar -->
                    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                        <!-- Nav Item - Search Dropdown (Visible Only XS) -->
                        <li class="nav-item dropdown no-arrow d-sm-none">
                            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="searchDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                                <i class="fas fa-search fa-fw"></i>
                            </a>
                            <!-- Dropdown - Messages -->
                            <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right p-3 shadow animated--grow-in" aria-labelledby="searchDropdown">
                                <form class="form-inline mr-auto w-100 navbar-search">
                                    <div class="input-group">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control bg-light border-0 small" placeholder="Search for..." aria-label="Search" aria-describedby="basic-addon2">
                                        <div class="input-group-append">
                                            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button">
                                                <i class="fas fa-search fa-sm"></i>
                                            </button>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </form>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <!-- Nav Item - Alerts -->
                        <li class="nav-item dropdown no-arrow mx-1">
                            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="alertsDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                                <i class="fas fa-bell fa-fw"></i>
                                <!-- Counter - Alerts -->
                                <span class="badge badge-danger badge-counter">3+</span>
                            </a>
                            <!-- Dropdown - Alerts -->
                            <div class="dropdown-list dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right shadow animated--grow-in" aria-labelledby="alertsDropdown">
                                <h6 class="dropdown-header">
                                    Alerts Center
                                </h6>
                                <a class="dropdown-item d-flex align-items-center" href="#">
                                    <div class="mr-3">
                                        <div class="icon-circle bg-primary">
                                            <i class="fas fa-file-alt text-white"></i>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div>
                                        <div class="small text-gray-500">December 12, 2019</div>
                                        <span class="font-weight-bold">A new monthly report is ready to download!</span>
                                    </div>
                                </a>
                                <a class="dropdown-item d-flex align-items-center" href="#">
                                    <div class="mr-3">
                                        <div class="icon-circle bg-success">
                                            <i class="fas fa-donate text-white"></i>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div>
                                        <div class="small text-gray-500">December 7, 2019</div>
                                        $290.29 has been deposited into your account!
                                    </div>
                                </a>
                                <a class="dropdown-item d-flex align-items-center" href="#">
                                    <div class="mr-3">
                                        <div class="icon-circle bg-warning">
                                            <i class="fas fa-exclamation-triangle text-white"></i>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div>
                                        <div class="small text-gray-500">December 2, 2019</div>
                                        Spending Alert: We've noticed unusually high spending for your account.
                                    </div>
                                </a>
                                <a class="dropdown-item text-center small text-gray-500" href="#">Show All Alerts</a>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <!-- Nav Item - Messages -->
                        <li class="nav-item dropdown no-arrow mx-1">
                            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="messagesDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                                <i class="fas fa-envelope fa-fw"></i>
                                <!-- Counter - Messages -->
                                <span class="badge badge-danger badge-counter">7</span>
                            </a>
                            <!-- Dropdown - Messages -->
                            <div class="dropdown-list dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right shadow animated--grow-in" aria-labelledby="messagesDropdown">
                                <h6 class="dropdown-header">
                                    Message Center
                                </h6>
                                <a class="dropdown-item d-flex align-items-center" href="#">
                                    <div class="dropdown-list-image mr-3">
                                        <img class="rounded-circle" src="https://source.unsplash.com/fn_BT9fwg_E/60x60" alt="">
                                        <div class="status-indicator bg-success"></div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="font-weight-bold">
                                        <div class="text-truncate">Hi there! I am wondering if you can help me with a problem I've been having.</div>
                                        <div class="small text-gray-500">Emily Fowler · 58m</div>
                                    </div>
                                </a>
                                <a class="dropdown-item d-flex align-items-center" href="#">
                                    <div class="dropdown-list-image mr-3">
                                        <img class="rounded-circle" src="https://source.unsplash.com/AU4VPcFN4LE/60x60" alt="">
                                        <div class="status-indicator"></div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div>
                                        <div class="text-truncate">I have the photos that you ordered last month, how would you like them sent to you?</div>
                                        <div class="small text-gray-500">Jae Chun · 1d</div>
                                    </div>
                                </a>
                                <a class="dropdown-item d-flex align-items-center" href="#">
                                    <div class="dropdown-list-image mr-3">
                                        <img class="rounded-circle" src="https://source.unsplash.com/CS2uCrpNzJY/60x60" alt="">
                                        <div class="status-indicator bg-warning"></div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div>
                                        <div class="text-truncate">Last month's report looks great, I am very happy with the progress so far, keep up the good work!</div>
                                        <div class="small text-gray-500">Morgan Alvarez · 2d</div>
                                    </div>
                                </a>
                                <a class="dropdown-item d-flex align-items-center" href="#">
                                    <div class="dropdown-list-image mr-3">
                                        <img class="rounded-circle" src="https://source.unsplash.com/Mv9hjnEUHR4/60x60" alt="">
                                        <div class="status-indicator bg-success"></div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div>
                                        <div class="text-truncate">Am I a good boy? The reason I ask is because someone told me that people say this to all dogs, even if they aren't good...</div>
                                        <div class="small text-gray-500">Chicken the Dog · 2w</div>
                                    </div>
                                </a>
                                <a class="dropdown-item text-center small text-gray-500" href="#">Read More Messages</a>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <div class="topbar-divider d-none d-sm-block"></div>
                        <!-- Nav Item - User Information -->
                        <li class="nav-item dropdown no-arrow">
                            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="userDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                                <span class="mr-2 d-none d-lg-inline text-gray-600 small">Valerie Luna</span>
                                <img class="img-profile rounded-circle" src="https://source.unsplash.com/QAB-WJcbgJk/60x60">
                            </a>
                            <!-- Dropdown - User Information -->
                            <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right shadow animated--grow-in" aria-labelledby="userDropdown">
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">
                                    <i class="fas fa-user fa-sm fa-fw mr-2 text-gray-400"></i>
                                    Profile
                                </a>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">
                                    <i class="fas fa-cogs fa-sm fa-fw mr-2 text-gray-400"></i>
                                    Settings
                                </a>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">
                                    <i class="fas fa-list fa-sm fa-fw mr-2 text-gray-400"></i>
                                    Activity Log
                                </a>
                                <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#logoutModal">
                                    <i class="fas fa-sign-out-alt fa-sm fa-fw mr-2 text-gray-400"></i>
                                    Logout
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
                <!-- End of Topbar -->
                <!-- Begin Page Content -->
                <!--ENTER PAGE CONTENT HERE-->
                <!-- /.container-fluid -->
            </div>
            <!-- End of Main Content -->
            <!-- Footer -->
            <footer class="sticky-footer bg-white">
                <div class="container my-auto">
                    <div class="copyright text-center my-auto">
                        <span>Copyright &copy; Your Website 2020</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </footer>
            <!-- End of Footer -->
        </div>
        <!-- End of Content Wrapper -->
    </div>
    <!-- End of Page Wrapper -->
    <!-- Scroll to Top Button-->
    <a class="scroll-to-top rounded" href="#page-top">
        <i class="fas fa-angle-up"></i>
    </a>
     Logout Modal
    @*<div class="modal fade" id="logoutModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Ready to Leave?</h5>
                    <button class="close" type="button" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">Select "Logout" below if you are ready to end your current session.</div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button class="btn btn-secondary" type="button" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                    <a class="btn btn-primary" href="login.html">Logout</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>*@
    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript-->
    <script src="~/DashboardStyles/vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/DashboardStyles/vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Core plugin JavaScript-->
    <script src="~/DashboardStyles/vendor/jquery-easing/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Custom scripts for all pages-->
    <script src="~/DashboardStyles/js/sb-admin-2.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: Facing issues with common layout have tried many times cannot get it right.]
Every View content goes here and there in layout.So help me solve the issues.

Answer (score 0):

I guess I have made a mistake in putting RenderBody() function it should come before Footer code.